# Comparing the number of real numbers between 2 ranges

Tags: number-theory, recreational-mathematics, infinity

I know that there are infinitely many number of real numbers between (1,2), (2,3) and so on and I know that there's no meaning to compare the number of real numbers between 2 ranges of real numbers but I've not been able to find fault with the below argument without bringing the concept of infinity. The argument goes like this:

Since each real number between (4,9) can be mapped to a unique real number between (2,3), after taking the square root, can't we say that the number of real numbers between (4,9) (whatever that number may be) is equal to the number of real numbers between (2,3)?

If we extend this argument, does this not mean that the **number of real numbers** between (4,5) is **smaller** than that between (2,3)!

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful and counterintuitive world of infinities. There are as many positive numbers as there are perfect squares, and that's just how it is.

Comment: (I mean positive _integers_, of course. Not positive numbers. Too late to edit.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must define the terms and expressions that you use first. If, when you say that two sets $A$ and $B$ of real numbers have the **same number** of elements what you mean is that there is a bijection between them, then, yes, $(4,9)$ and $(2,3)$ have the same number of elements. Actualy, *any* two open (or closed, for that matter) intervals have the same number of elements. Take $(2,3)$ and $(4,5)$, for instance, and consider the bijection $f\colon(2,3)\longrightarrow(4,5)$ defined by $f(x)=x+2$.

Analogously, if you want to say that one set of real numbers is **smaller** than another one, you must explain first what is it that you mean by that.

Comment: PS. The standard way of defining that one set is "smaller than" another isn't that there is an injective, non-bijective function from one to the other, but rather that _any_ injective function is non-bijective. For finite sets this makes no difference, but for infinite sets it does.

Comment: By smaller, I had meant that there are lesser number of elements in the set (4,5) in comparison to (2,3). Btw, the function that you have taken in your answer takes us to a different conclusion. I've never really understood infinity. It has just been a word which answers a lot of question, like this one, without the need of actually understanding the reasoning.

Comment: @VishalSharma But then you must define the meaning of **there are lesser number of elements**.

Comment: I didn't realise that the statement is ambiguous! Maybe you can help me here by telling me how it is not well defined. I simply meant the count of elements in the set like in the set of {1,2,3} we have 3 elements...like this

Comment: @VishalSharma And how did you count the number of elements of the sets $(4,5)$ and $(2,3)$ in order to deduce that the former has a lesser number of elements that the later?

Comment: I mapped all the elements in the set (2,3) with the set (4,9) by the help of the square root function. I then theorized that (4,5) should have a lesser number of real numbers then (4,9). Using this theory I reached my conclusion.

Comment: @VishalSharma This comment is inconsistent with the previous one, in which you spoke about counting the elements of $\{1,2,3\}$. And there's still the problem of explaing what **have a lesser number of real numbers then** means.

Comment: Sir, I've tried my best of stating clearly what I meant. Also I don't see any inconsistency (That is why I asked the question). I think the main question I'm trying to ask is this: When a bijection exists between 2 sets, can I represent the number of elements in each of them by, say, n? If yes can I not use this number as comparison with other sets?

Comment: @VishalSharma When there is a bijection between two sets then, yes, you can say that they have the same number of elements (although I don't know what that $n$ is when the sets are infinite). The problem begins when you claim that the number of elements of a set is smaller that the number of elements of another set.

Comment: I am revisiting this comment after so many days and I still got confused. When you say that the number of elements are same in the 2 sets(A and B) if a bijection exists, why does that not mean that A has got more number of elements as compared to a subset of B??

Comment: Or am I wrong in considering [4,5] as a subset of [4,9]? Why?

Comment: I only answer one comment at a time, at most.